# Randomize list in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to randomize the elements of an array using just functions from WDL in Logic apps?

Comment: What result do you want? Randomized array or one item?

Comment: Randomized array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine you have array from 1 to 10

[image]

You create one lement randomized array variable

```
first(variables('Array'))
```

[image]

And a temp value (**tempValue**) and temp array (**temp**) (used in later steps because self referencing is not allowed)

[image]

Then you create **until** loop like so

[image]

With Until condition being

```
equals(length(variables('Randomized')), length(variables('Array')))
```

Calculate random index **tempValue** in array (random index at which we will split array)

```
rand(0,sub(length('Randomized'),1))
```

And combine new array **temp** by inserting current iteration value at random place

```
union(
  take(
    variables('Randomized'),
    variables('tempInteger')
  ),
  array(variables('Array')[add(iterationIndexes('Until'),1)]),
  skip(
    variables('Randomized'),
    variables('tempInteger')
  )
)
```

And after condition statement set **randomized** variable to **temp** value

Which after the last iteration will net you randomized input table

[image]

And full code example

```
{
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
      "Init_Randomized_One_Element_Array": {
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "Randomized",
              "type": "Array",
              "value": [
                "@first(variables('Array'))"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Init_Unrandomized_Array": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
      },
      "Init_Randomized_Temp_Array": {
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "temp",
              "type": "Array"
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Init_Randomized_One_Element_Array": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
      },
      "Init_Temp_Calculated_Value": {
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "tempInteger",
              "type": "integer"
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Init_Randomized_Temp_Array": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
      },
      "Init_Unrandomized_Array": {
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "Array",
              "type": "Array",
              "value": [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5,
                6,
                7,
                8,
                9,
                10
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
      },
      "Until": {
        "actions": {
          "Add_random_element_to_temp_array": {
            "inputs": {
              "name": "temp",
              "value": "@union(\r\n\ttake(\r\n\t\t   variables('Randomized'),\r\n\t\t   variables('tempInteger')\r\n\t),\r\n\tarray(variables('Array')[add(iterationIndexes('Until'),1)]),\r\n\tskip(\r\n\t   variables('Randomized'),\r\n\t   variables('tempInteger')\r\n\t)\r\n)\r\n"
            },
            "runAfter": {
              "Random_Index_to_insert": [
                "Succeeded"
              ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
          },
          "Random_Index_to_insert": {
            "inputs": {
              "name": "tempInteger",
              "value": "@rand(0,sub(length('Randomized'),1))"
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "SetVariable"
          },
          "Set_randomized_from_temp": {
            "inputs": {
              "name": "Randomized",
              "value": "@variables('temp')"
            },
            "runAfter": {
              "Add_random_element_to_temp_array": [
                "Succeeded"
              ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
          }
        },
        "expression": "@equals(length(variables('Randomized')), length(variables('Array')))",
        "limit": {
          "count": 60,
          "timeout": "PT1H"
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Init_Temp_Calculated_Value": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "Until"
      }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {},
    "triggers": {
      "manual": {
        "inputs": {
          "schema": {}
        },
        "kind": "Http",
        "type": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but this is not randomized enough. The last element (for instance) always occurs at the first or the last place. I solved this issue by repeating this block length of Array times.

Comment: Updated answer for full randomization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to randomize anything in a LogicApp.

I suppose you could come up with some pattern that could pseudorandomize a list entirely within a Logic App, but....

The more 'correct' way to handle this would be with a Function.